# Compatibility of differentiable structures.

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

It was, at first, a question that i asked, but i was so confused, that i deleted it. In the meantime, i think i answered it,  but i am not sure wether or not my answer is correct.

I had troubles understanding the solution to the following problem :

> Let $\varphi, \psi :  R \rightarrow R $ be defined as
> $\varphi(x) = x^3$ and  $\psi(x) = x$ for (x<0) and $\psi(x) = 2x (x \geq 0)$.
>
> Do the atlases $A_1 = \{ id_R\}$,$A_2 = \{\varphi \}$  and $A_3 = \{ \psi(x) \}$ induce different differentiable structures on $R$ ?

The official solution to the problem states :

> The three atlases induce different $C^\infty$ structures on $R$ as the identity map from $(R,A_i)$ to $(R,A_j)$ $ i \neq j$ is not a diffeomorphism (ie, the charts are not $C^\infty$-compatible).

Why is this right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i approach the problem :

1. If i take the coordinate change onto itself, $A_1$ is $C^\infty$ since $x \circ x = x$ and $x$ is $C^\infty$. $A_2$ gives us $ x^3 \circ x^{1/3} = x$ and $x$ is $C^\infty$ and similarly, for $A_3$ we also get $x$.
2. $\Phi = \cup_i A_i$ is an atlas. But both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are not diffeomorphisms, since the first one, has no derivative for it's inverse at $0$. The second one, has no well defined derivative at $0$. Meaning, the charts are not $C^\infty$ compatible, since the coordinate changes would not give us diffeomorphisms. For example, the change from $A_2$ to $A_1$ would give us : $x \circ x^{1/3} $ which is not differentiable at $0$.
3. Applying an analoguous reasoning to $A_3$ (we just showed $A_1$ to $A_2$) shows why the identity map from $(R,A_i)$ to $(R,A_j)$ $ i \neq j$ is not a diffeomorphism, since it's not a differentiable map from with differentiable inverse for $(R,A_i)$, $(R,A_j)$ for $i\neq j$ (at least one direction blocks you always).

It's not because the maps are not diffeomorphisms, that the structure that they induce is not $C^\infty$. However, as soon as you play with different charts, you have to be more careful.